# How to get checked checkbox values as checked in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get checked the checkbox value if this is checked

Here is my code:

```
<?php
      foreach ($dosage_form_list as $val) {
 ?>  

    <input type="checkbox" name="dosage_form_input[]" value="<?php echo $val['dosage_form']?>">

    <?php echo $val['dosage_form'];?>

    <?php

       }

     ?>
```

Comment: you will get "on" if checkbox checked, else not getting params so you can manage from backend.

Comment: If my checkbox value is found then it should be on checked.

Comment: can i see the data inside your database? maybe i can help you to build the code.

Comment: I have collected more than 10 checkbox data But It should be checked 3-4 values. But I got only one value with checked Here is the code: `<input type="checkbox" name="dosage_form_input[]" value="<?php echo $val['dosage_form']?>" <?php echo ($dosage_form_list_exist == $val['dosage_form'] ? 'checked' : null); ?>>` `dosage_form_list_exist ` is get multiple values!

Comment: Hey, @curiosity Can you please check my latest updated question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution:

```
   <?php
$dosage_form_list_exist = preg_replace('/\s*,\s*/', ',', 
$dosage_form_list_exist); // It removes spaces after the comma only not 
 between the values like "Oral Solutions" etc
// $dosage_form_list_exist = str_replace(' ', '', $dosage_form_list_exist); 
// It removes all the spaces from the Variable
$dosage_list = explode(',',$dosage_form_list_exist);
foreach ($dosage_form_list as $val) {
?>  

<input type="checkbox" name="dosage_form_input[]" value="<?php echo 
$val['dosage_form']?>" <?php echo (in_array($val['dosage_form'],$dosage_list) 
? 'checked' : ''); ?>>

<?php echo $val['dosage_form'];?>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just append `checked=checked` if you need it to be.. checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="dosage_form_input[]" value="<?php echo $val['dosage_form']?>" checked="<?= $someConditional ? 'checked' : ''; ?>">
```

Comment: I also want to know why my post is also getting downvote?

Comment: @Sabbir I don't know, I didn't downvote it, just answered with something I thought might help you

Comment: `checked="<?= $someConditional ? 'checked' : '';` why I use some condition? @matit

Comment: To decide whether it should be checked or not

Comment: It should be checked if My specific value is found

Comment: But your mentioned code is shows all the checkbox checked.

Comment: @Sabbir what you tried to check the checkbox? show your code

Comment: Sabbir, you need to probably have some functionality behind $someConditional as well.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="dosage_form_input[]" value="<?php echo $val['dosage_form']?>" checked="<?= $val['dosage_form'] ? 'checked' : ''; ?>">` I use this

Comment: and it will work as long as $val['dosage_form'] evaluates to false when you need no checked checkbox

Comment: Can you please check again my question? I mentioned I already getting all the checkbox value in codeigniter update from. Only checked value which is selected for specific id in edit from?

Comment: I got a solution but sometimes it returns no checked value:: `<input type="checkbox" name="dosage_form_input[]" value="<?php echo $val['dosage_form']?>" <?php echo ($dosage_form_list_exist == $val['dosage_form'] ? 'checked' : null); ?>>`

Comment: yes, it does when dosage_form_list_exist == $val['dosage_form'] is false, which sounds reasonable?

Comment: So If I get dosage_form_list_exist is multiple values What can I do Now?

Comment: I don't know exactly, I don't know how your data structures look like. You just need to display checked=checked only when you need it - and this is controlled by that conditional

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187427/discussion-between-sabbir-and-matiit).